# Convert Date dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have this code

```
    Dim conex As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(conxst)
    Dim caixa As Integer = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
    Dim verdat As Date = DateTimePicker1.Text
    Dim verdat1 As Date = "05/07/2012"
    conex.Open()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select codigo,data,horario from alteraca where data = '" & verdat1 & "' ", conex)
    da.Fill(dt)
```

this code work when verdat1 is in the format "mm/dd/yyyy" , how i convert the date from mine datetimepicker (dd/mm/yyyy) to the format "mm/dd/yyyy" to place in the statment??? Thanks.

Comment: Please [never do that](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
verdat1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

You can select how the date is converted to a string.

Also, you can set the `dateTimePicker` Custom Format as you wish :

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use string representation of a value when you already have binary representation.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Using conex As New SqlConnection(conxst)
    conex.Open()

    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select codigo, data, horario from alteraca where data = @data", conex)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DateTimePicker1.Value)

        Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)
        End Using
    End Using

End Using
```

Comment: this code have no error, but i think i have explained bad, my problem is  the datetimepicker1  are in this format dd/mm/yyyy but the format of the column data is mm/dd/yyyy , i need a method for convert the value of datetimepicker to dd/mm/yyyy to compare in the statement with the value data. Thanks by thehelp

Comment: @alejandrocarnero Are you saying the column has data type `varchar(x)`? If it is, it's WRONG, but you can then insert the value of `datetimepicker1.Value.ToString("MM\/dd\/yyyy")`. Otherwise the format of datetime picker does not matter, because, as I said, you should not confuse values and their string representation.

Comment: Even if the column datatype is varchar, that should still work (on SQL Servers configured for the US), as varchar gets an implicit conversion when compared to a date value, and AddWithValue with a date value will create a parameter with dbType DateTime.

Comment: this is the format of  my datetimepicker.value 26/07/2012(dd/mm/yyyy), the format of the column data(datetime) is 07/26/2012(mm/dd/yyyy) this reason i need to convert from one format to the other

Comment: @alejandrocarnero `datetimepicker.value` does *not* have any format. It is a binary value. `dd/mm/yyyy` is a template used to convert this binary value when it comes to showing it to the user.

Answer (score 1):

In sql query 
-use to_date to convert String to date
-and to char for reverse

In your case
`select codigo,data,horario from alteraca where data = to_date('" & verdat1 & "','dd/mm/yyyy') ", conex`

here `'dd/mm/yyyy'` is format of your variable...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a better (and safer way) to do the query is to use Parameters and `Using` statements.  The `Using` statement automatically closes the connection, commands and adapter.

```
Dim caixa As Integer = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
Dim verdat As Date = DateTimePicker1.Text
Dim verdat1 As Date = "05/07/2012"
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim dt As New DataTable

Using conex as New SQLConnection(conxst)
  conex.Open()
  Using cmdex as New SQLCommand("select codigo,data,horario from alteraca where data = @DATE " , conxst)
   cmdex.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE",verdat1)
   Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdex)
     da.Fill(dt)
   End Using
  End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date like this:

```
verdat1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use DateTimePicker1.value. It is easily solve